# How to fixed a table header left section and right section scroll only middle section

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

I'm searching in the result but I have not found any result.

I want to a simple table,
and now i have three questions:

1. is how to fixed of a header  (Bold Text area)
2. how to fixed left section  (1 type text area)
3. how to fixed right section (7 type text are )

**HTML**

```
<div class="m-m">
<table class="demo-table">
    <tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>fixed area</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>fixed area</td>
    </tr>

</table>
</div>
```

**Css**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
.m-m{
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:0 auto;
overflow:scroll;
}
.demo-table{
border:solid 1px red;
width:100%;

}
.demo-table tr:first-child td{
font-weight:bold;
}

.demo-table tr td{
border:solid 2px green;
padding:5px;
}
```

I want to result this

[image]

Comment: I doubt you can achieve this in any sort of elegant way. If this markup is for layout you should not be using <table> anyway. If you can elaborate on your use case (what is the content/context, why do you want some of it fixed) it will be easier to suggest alternatives.

Comment: @xec I know about position fixed but this is tabular data so i need in table .........

Comment: Not to be glib but response of "I have to use a table" results in "I have to look at someone else's question" pretty quickly - restriction of possible options means no options in lots of cases.  Best of luck.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I need to this solution and now i m using table and client say that Table Header , table left section , table right section Fixed and middle section only chage when i scroll the page .....

Comment: As long as it LOOKS like a table, ACTS like a table do they really REALLY CARE if the markup IS a table?

Comment: For all the same semantic markup reasons that one should not use a table for non-tabular-data, one SHOULD use a table for tabular data if possible. It's the other side of the same coin. If you look at the post, the markup isn't for layout, it's for displaying a table of data.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the image explains better what you want to do. If you are able to set a fixed width on both the header and the body of the table you could set them apart.

I placed a jsFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/3Lxj3/1/ that might help.

```
<div id="header">
     <div style="width:40%;">header 1</div>
     <div style="width:30%;">header 2</div>
     <div style="width:30%;">header 3</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
<div id="left">
    <div>row 1</div>
    <div>row 2</div>
    <div>row 3</div>
    <div>row 4</div>
</div>
<div id="body">
     <table>
     <tr>
     <td style="width:40%;">contents 1</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 2</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 3</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:40%;">contents 1</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 2</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 3</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:40%;">contents 1</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 2</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 3</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style="width:40%;">contents 1</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 2</td>
     <td style="width:30%;">contents 3</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="right">
    <div>check 1</div>
    <div>check 2</div>
    <div>check 3</div>
    <div>check 4</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#body table {
width:100%;
}
#header, #left, #body table {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
table tr td {
    height:50px;
}
#header {
    margin-left:20%;
    margin-right:20%;
    width:59%;
}
#header div {
    float:left;
}
#body {
    width:59%;
    float:left;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:200px;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
}
#left div {
    height:50px;
}
#right {
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
}
#right div {
    height:50px;
}
```

Basically you place the header and the body separate but make sure they align vertically. It's not pretty, but it works.

Comment: It doesn't work for me - if I add enough rows for it to actually scroll, the row headings continue down the page while the rows of data are limited to the scroll box. Same if you have enough headings to scroll off to the right. And, of course, when that happens, if you scroll the data, the headings don't scroll with it.

Comment: @Adrian: That's because it's not supposed to. Rohit Azad wrote that he wants the horizontal and the vertical headers to be fixed, as well as the checkboxes on the right. I this _not_ how I would have solved this otherwise... :-)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what OP wanted, based on the screenshot he posted.